# Will BatchNorm be trained in Tensorflow if layers get frozen but is_training is True?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning, batch-normalization, pre-trained-model

I am trying to perform some transfer learning, in which I have to freeze the first several layers of my pertained model, and only fine-tune the last several layers with a different dataset.

I know that, if we are not freezing anything, we just set is_training to True during training and is_training to false during testing. But now I was wondering what the behavior of Batch-norm will be like if I exclude the frozen layers from trainable variables with is_training to be True.

In order to freeze layer "A", "B" and "C", I did something like this:

```
tvars = tf.contrib.framework.filter_variables(tf.trainable_variables(), exclude_patterns = ['A', 'B', 'C'])
grad = optimizer.comput_gradient(some_loss, tvars)
```

But I am not sure how I should set "is_training" during training...
To my understanding, there are 2 trainable variables "gamma" and "beta" for BatchNorm. If I really hope to freeze "A", "B", "C", I need to disable the updating ops for them. However, the mean and variance still needs to be updated during transfer-learning, am I right?

I am new to transfer learning, could anyone provide some guidance on how Batch norm should be handled for the frozen layers in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Batch normalization adds two trainable parameters to each layer, so the normalized output is multiplied by a “standard deviation” parameter (gamma) and add a “mean” parameter (beta)

When you set `training = False` that means the batch normalization layer will use its internally stored average of mean and variance to normalize the batch(like in inference mode), not the batch's own mean and variance. When training = False, those internal variables also don't get updated. Since they are initialized to mean = 0 and variance = 1 it means that batch normalization is effectively turned off - the layer subtracts zero and divides the result by 1.

If you turn on batch normalization with `training = True` that will start to normalize the batches within themselves and collect a moving average of the mean and variance of each batch.